# How to handle multiple(100s) input files in hadoop2 where size of each of those files is less than 10MB?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Let us suppose that I have 200 input files each of size 10MB. //total_size=2GB

How can i make these files to get stored in 16 HDFS blocks? //default_block_size=128MB

By doing so, I think 16 mappers will do my work efficiently compared to 200 mappers for 200 input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store multiple files inside a single block in HDFS, this is basic rule of HDFS. In your case HDFS blocks are not well used, out of total 128MB in a block only 10MB is used and remaining 118 MB cannot be used by any other file, and it will remain free. (one thing to note here is, HDFS blocks are logical, your HDFS blocks will take only 10MB of physical storage though you have set to it to 128MB.)

in short in HDFS, file to HDFS-blocks relation is one to many and HDFS-blocks to files cannot be one to many.

Comment: you can simply write a sequence file which contains each file as a record.

Comment: yes, or else you can first load into a temp table (if files are in s3, you can create an external table) then insert into your core table.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to change your process that writes to HDFS to save a file which is equal (or) approximately equal to the block size. This will ensure that you are optimizing a block size and when any job is executed on the Hadoop Cluster, it will spin up the number of number of map tasks equal to block or split.

An ideal approach if your input data set is too large is to compress the data further and then save in HDFS. This will reduce the footprint of data saved in the cluster and improve the performance of the job reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot store in that way ( 16 HDFS blocks ).

In order to spawn around 16 mappers for the files,you can use [CombileFileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0-alpha2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html) , so that it combines file until the provided limit is met. ( different in boundary cases ).

Need to specify :- **mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize** and **mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize**